# Type safety: The expression of type array needs unchecked conversion to conform to employee<String,Integer>[] means

Tags: java

What does Type safety: *The expression of type employee[] needs unchecked conversion to conform to employee[] means*?? 
And how to get rid out of it.

I got it on the   `this.e = new employee[length];` line in the following :

```
class employee<U, T> {

    public U name;

    public T id;

    public employee(U name, T id) {
        this.name = name;
        this.id = id;
    }

 // setter - gettter
 ....
}



class manageEmployee {

    private employee<String, Integer> e[];

    public manageEmployee(employee<String, Integer> e[], int length) {

      this.e = new employee[length];
        this.e = e;

    }

  ......
   .....
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are assigning an array of raw `employee` type - `new employee[length]` - to a variable of an array of parameterized `employee<String, Integer>` type. This requires a cast.

However, since in the following line (`this.e = e;`) you assign the array parameter of the constructor to the `e` member of the class, there's no point to the `this.e = new employee[length];` line at all, since it creates an array instance that can be immediately garbage collected.

EDIT:

To create an instance of the array in your main method :

```
employee<String,Integer> e[] = (employee<String,Integer>[]) new employee[5];
```

This will result in a warning, but there's no way around it, since you can't create an instance of a parameterized array.

Comment: i still get the same issue while I instiate the array in `main method`, `employee<String,Integer> e[] = new employee[5];` , how do I parameterize that  array anyway??

Comment: @hansf.Since you can't create an instance of a parameterized array, you must cast the raw array type to the parameterized type.